# Double quote string escape node eval javascript

Tags: node.js, string, unix, double-quotes

I have a node file with this content inside:

```
console.log("hello \"\"world")
```

When I log this I get:

```
hello ""world
```

I would like to put this in node's -e (eval) flag.

I'm conceptually not undestanding how I could "clean" this string so that it would give the same output.

```
node -e "console.log(\"hello \\"\\"world\")"
hello \world
```

This works but adds an extra slash

What would I have to do with the contents of the eval to make it valid and work as expected?

Comment: What would you want to print eventually? `hello ""world` or some other

Comment: @Inian I want to print `hello ""world` using -e

Comment: What about just `node -e "console.log("hello \"\"world")"`

Answer (score 1):

You need two more slashes:

```
node -e "console.log(\"hello \\\"\\\"world\")"
```

Both the `\` and the `"` need to be escaped.